# How to find specific file in command prompt

Tags: file, cmd, command-prompt

I need to find **one** file - the oldest one- in command prompt. I know how to list files by their "age" or size etc., but is there a way to get cmd to show me only the oldest file? Only that one? Thanks

Comment: The oldest file in where? A drive, a tree branch, a folder, a set of files?

Comment: a drive or a file, i would love to know how to do it in both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `forfiles` command, and modify it to your needs using the `/d` to do it. More information about the command can be found on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out! But mainly thanks for sharing this site, never used it before but it seems to be a perfect source of information about command prompt!

Comment: @Pauline No problem. If this helps answer your question,please mark it as the correct answer. :)